# Human selection of date using Selenium Ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm working on automating the download of some reports located in a web site.
Using Selenium Ide 2.9.1 and Firefox 46.0 is all ok, except for one operation: selecting the date from a calendar.

I mean: all has to be automatic except for selecting the date, because it's a requirement known only by the user. For example, today the user could be interested about what happened yesterday, or maybe about what happened the 1st of march.

So, if possible (i'm not sure), at the moment of selecting the date, the play case has to be stopped for allowing the user choose the date, selecting from the calendar or typing it.

At the moment, I've identified the matching nodes with Firebug. I can also use Fire Path.

But now, I need some suggestions.

Thank you.